# Shuffling the rows in a Spark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a new column in a data frame that is simply a shuffled version of an existing column. I'm able to randomly order the rows in a data frame using the method described in [How to shuffle the rows in a Spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637625/how-to-shuffle-the-rows-in-a-spark-dataframe?rq=1), but when I try to add the shuffled version of the column to a data frame, it appears to not perform the shuffling.

```py
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.range(5).toDF("x")
df.show()
#> +---+
#> |  x|
#> +---+
#> |  0|
#> |  1|
#> |  2|
#> |  3|
#> |  4|
#> +---+

# the rows appear to be shuffled
ordered_df = df.orderBy(F.rand())
ordered_df.show()
#> +---+
#> |  x|
#> +---+
#> |  0|
#> |  2|
#> |  3|
#> |  4|
#> |  1|
#> +---+

# ...but when i try to add this column to the df, they are no longer shuffled
df.withColumn('y', ordered_df.x).show()
#> +---+---+
#> |  x|  y|
#> +---+---+
#> |  0|  0|
#> |  1|  1|
#> |  2|  2|
#> |  3|  3|
#> |  4|  4|
#> +---+---+
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-28 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>

A few notes:

- I would like to find a solution where the data remains in Spark. For example, I don't want to have to use a user-defined function that requires that the data be moved out of the JVM.
- The solution in [PySpark: Randomize rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803030/pyspark-randomize-rows-in-dataframe/36806385#36806385) didn't work for me (see below).

```py
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(5)).map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["x"])

df.withColumn('y', df.orderBy(F.rand()).x).show()
#> +---+---+
#> |  x|  y|
#> +---+---+
#> |  0|  0|
#> |  1|  1|
#> |  2|  2|
#> |  3|  3|
#> |  4|  4|
#> +---+---+
```

- I have to shuffle the rows in many columns, and each column has to be shuffled independently of the others. As such, I would prefer to not use the `zipWithIndex()` solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889539, as that solution would require that I run many joins on the data (which i'm assuming will be time-intensive).

Comment: Look at the execution plan: `df.withColumn('y', ordered_df.x).explain()`. Spark is lazy, so `ordered_df` is not cached or saved anywhere. When you call `withColumn`, it's calculated again. Shuffling the columns independently is just not something spark is designed to do well. Each row is processed as a atomic unit - this is what allows spark to parallelize row operations across executors. I don't think there's any way to avoid doing a join.

Comment: Why would the fact that the ordering step (`df.orderBy(F.rand())`) has to be re-run when I call `df.withColumn('y', ordered_df.x).show()` result in the reordering not being done at all (or at least that's how it appears)? In other words, I don't understand why the fact that Spark is lazy would impact this case.

Comment: For example, if you I add a call to `ordered_df.cache()`, I still run into the problem that I described.

Comment: I think you have some misunderstandings about lazy execution. One example is to run `ordered_df.show()` multiple times - you'll see that you get a different result each time. Spark doesn't "save" any of the values - only the instructions on how to create those values.

Comment: I know that Spark doesn't actually do the work until an action is called - My point is that lazy execution shouldn't be to blame for me not getting what I expect. For example, why doesn't `df.withColumn('y', df.orderBy(F.rand()).x).show()` show the column (`y`) as being reordered? An action is called (`show()`), so `y` should be randomly ordered, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using window functions to assign each row a random index, doing this again in a separate DF, and then joining on the index:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df = spark.range(5).toDF("x")
>>> left = df.withColumn("rnd", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.rand())))
>>> right = df.withColumnRenamed("x", "y").withColumn("rnd", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.rand()))) 
>>> dff = left.join(right, left.rnd == right.rnd).drop("rnd")
>>> dff.show()
19/06/29 13:17:04 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
19/06/29 13:17:04 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---+---+                                                                       
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  3|  3|
|  2|  0|
|  0|  2|
|  1|  1|
|  4|  4|
+---+---+
```

As the warning suggests, this might not be a great idea in practice.